# Passing arguments to subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, silent-installer

I faced unpleasant situation with silent installation of some program. I am not sure that they use any convention for installation flags with values but here what should be used for installation:

```
"path with spaces\setup.exe" -uninst -s -f2"path with spaces\uninstall.log"
```

you cannot use --f2="path with spaces\uninstall.log" or -f2="path with spaces\uninstall.log" or -f2 "path with spaces\uninstall.log"

so if I use in Python following:

```
command = [self.setup_exe, '-uninst', '-s', fr'-f2"{uninstall_log_file}"']
```

command that subprocess is executing (get from *subprocess.list2cmdline(command)*) is:

```
setup.exe" -uninst -s -f2\"some path\temp build 12\uninstall.log\"
```

basically slashes appear and installation is failing.
Theoretically I can create my own string but the same provider for another executable provides another syntax which is more compatible with subprocess. I am wondering if it is possible to setup a list of arguments to satisfy reqs of installer?

Comment: How are you actually calling the command? It looks like you may be using `shell=True` when you shouldn't be.

Comment: @chepner, you are right, I am using shell=True. As far as I understood this  is needed in case if I need to run command as elevated user (for example with PowerShell). Or will it work any case?

Comment: No, using `shell=True` just switches from executing the command directly to running a shell with a constructed argument to have the shell run the command for you.

Comment: here is how I call now: subprocess.call(command)

Comment: @chepner, now it is creating another layer of quotes: "-f2\"some path\uninstall.log\""

Comment: You included the quotes in your definition of `command`: `fr'-f2"{uinstall_log_file}"'`. You can omit them.

Comment: @chepner, unfortunately not, then it is treating the whole argument as with space and makes "-f2path....". Does not work :(

Comment: What is the actual value of `uninstall_log_file`, and what is the actual command you use to run the executable?

Comment: @chepner, see first command in the question. Basically it might be any path containing space. Path is requested from user. For example C:\Test 1 2 3 4\log.log

Comment: That's how you might invoke it from the shell command line. What is the actual *Python* code you use to run the command?

Comment: I think I replied. subprocess.call(command). I tried both shell and non shell

Comment: Then the problem is your definition of `command`, as I pointed out earlier. You are adding quotes intended to prevent the shell from processing the value of `uninstall_log_file`, but there *is* no such shell. Try `command = [..., '-f2', uninstall_log_file]`.

Comment: I am ready to give up with syntax used for this silent. It is easier to construct string by myself. I do not think it is possible through list

Comment: @chepner, no, I cannot use it. It is not possible to have space between -f2 and path

Comment: As in question: 

you cannot use --f2="path with spaces\uninstall.log" or -f2="path with spaces\uninstall.log" or -f2 "path with spaces\uninstall.log"

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
"path with spaces\setup.exe" -uninst -s -f2"path with spaces\uninstall.log"
```

from the command line, the equivalent call to `subprocess.call` is

```
uninstall_log_file = r"path with spaces\uninstall.log"
command = [self.setup_exe, '-uninst', '-s', f'-f2{uninstall_log_file}']
subprocess.call(command)
```

Comment: unfortunately this ill not work, I tried this already. If I put a path without spaces it will work. If I put a path with spaces then not since argument will look like "-f2path with spaces/log.log". So this does not work

Comment: I also tried this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022687/python-subprocess-argument-with-equal-sign-and-space
however I assume difference in provider. Since there the argument will look like -f2=path with spaces.
In my example from CMD equal sign is not allowed

Comment: I made a slight adjustment to the answer, making `uninstall_log_file` the raw string rather than the f-string that interpolates the value. I'm not sure if that will make a difference.

Comment: just performed the test. Unfortunately no. I executed subprocess with list but for check also ran list2cmdline. It is adding quotes around -f2 -> "-f2path". So installation fails.

what is working but weird is:
command = [f'"{self.setup_exe}"', '-uninst', '-s', fr'-f2"{uninstall_log_file}"']
command = " ".join(command)

and then call subprocess with a string.

Do you think it is possible to get the same using list?